# Attempt to de-reference a null Object Email Service Test Class

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, failing-tests

I'm trying to build a test class for me to move an Email Service class into Prod, but I'm getting this error.

Here is part of my code (The important bits)

**Email Service Class**

```
global class emailInbdounds implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler{

global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email,Messaging.InboundEnvelope env)
{
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
    String myPlainText= '';
    myPlainText =email.subject + '\n' +  email.plainTextBody;
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest(seeAlldata=True) private class testSendEmail {

@isTest static void testIdontKnow(){
    Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail() ;
    Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope = new Messaging.InboundEnvelope();

    email.subject = 'Test';
    email.fromName = 'test test';
    email.plainTextBody = 'Hello, this a test';

Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment[] binaryAttachments = new Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment[1];  
Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment binaryAttachment = new Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment();
binaryAttachment.Filename = 'test.txt';
String algorithmName = 'HMacSHA1';

Blob b = Crypto.generateMac(algorithmName, Blob.valueOf('test'),Blob.valueOf('test_key'));
binaryAttachment.Body = b;
binaryAttachments[0] =  binaryAttachment ;
email.binaryAttachments = binaryAttachments ;
envelope.fromAddress = 'user@acme.com';

emailInbdounds catcher = new emailInbdounds();

catcher.handleInboundEmail(email, envelope);


           
}



}
```

The error comes on the last line :

```
catcher.handleInboundEmail(email, envelope);
```

Based on my research , this error appears when the Data Type you are creating has not been initialized, but, the line prior to this one, already does that.

```
emailInbdounds catcher = new emailInbdounds();
```

Comment: Seems like the null reference exception is occurring inside the `handleInboundEmail` method. So, unless you post the code for this method, I doubt anyone would be able help you out.

Comment: You are absolutely right, the issue was related to some strings that when testing the method, were not getting initialized. It worked just as a Class, but when testing , it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a ton of information and just trying to fix the testMethod, I started debugging the actual Email service Class, and that's where I found the error.
For some reason, the Email Service class is working fine on its own, but when testing it, the List of Strings I had setup, were not getting initialized, hence the error.

Hope this helps someone in the future.
TLDR: You need to make sure your Email Service class works fine when testing, and not only on its own!!